# Create dynamic trigger on created table, from a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, azure-sql-database, ddl, dml

Sounds a bit confusing, but this is what I'm attempting to do. I have a trigger on table creation for a database. I want to then take this table that was created, and create a trigger on it that listens to insert. What I have so far:

```
USE DatabaseA;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [TableCreationTrigger] ON DATABASE AFTER CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Data XML = EVENTDATA();

DECLARE @CreatedTable varchar(60);
SET @CreatedTable = @Data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)');

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '
    CREATE TRIGGER CreatedTableTrigger  
        ON ' + @CreatedTable + '  
        AFTER INSERT AS  
        BEGIN 
            select * into InsertedTest from inserted
        END';
EXEC(@sql);
END
GO
```

But so far I'm not seeing this trigger being created. Am I missing something? Or is this just not possible? If not possible, is there a solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: How are the tables created?  I'm not sure if it is possible to create a trigger using an existing trigger, but nothing is stopping you from creating it programmatically in the same code that the tables are created in.

Comment: They're being created through an SSIS using OLE DB